# Counting the days

Tags: android, android-studio, time

I want to make application order to show toast after 00:00 or show toast message 24 hours after installPlease tell me how can I do it? I tried to get the clock of the phone and compare it to the intended clock,but it did not succeed.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: You can only show Toasts when your app is in the foreground. If you want to show information to the user even if your app is closed you need to use notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Use JobSchedule to schedule at 00:00 and start a foreground service that will generate this toast. Thus, the toast message will appear, bacause the foreground service is like a foreground app.

In summary:

1. JobSchedule scheduled to work at 00:00
2. JobSchedule processing starts a foreground service
3. Foreground service make the toast
4. Foreground service finish

For reference:

1. [JobSchedule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)
2. [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)